# Cordova 3.5.0 how to add Custom plugin Using CLI?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am using cordova3.5.0 and i want to add my custom plugin to my project using CLI .I don't know what is the procedure to add own plugin to my project.Although i can add their native plugin simply type cordova add plugin org.apache.cordova.camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lot of R&D i found there is only solution ,We can add custom plugin only manually not using CLI.

Comment: Use CLI to add as like any other plugin but provide path to the local folder where custom plugin is put.

Answer (score 3):

You can just type cordova plugin add

Just point it to an directory with a valid plugin.xml. See documentation for the plugin.xml here:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

Cordova help says the following: plugin add  [ ...] .......... SPEC can be a plugin ID, a local path, or a git URL.

Comment: Thanks for respons.. i am getting error like C:\Users\alex\demoGap>cordova plugins add ContactChooserPlugin
Fetching plugin "ContactChooserPlugin" via plugin registry
Error: Failed to fetch package information for ContactChooserPlugin
    at C:\Users\alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cor
dova-lib\src\plugman\registry\registry.js:32:20
    at Request.cb [as _callback] (C:\Users\alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\registry\registry.js:251:9)
    at Request.self.callback

Comment: So your plugin is already in the demoGap folder? Not sure if that works, what I normally do is putting it in a parent folder and than reference it like this: cordova plugin add ..\<folder>. In your case you might need to execute cordova plugin add ./ContactChooserPlugin?

Comment: I ran into the same issue. The plugin can't be in the same destination folder as you suggest. After moving it `cordova plugin add <other_dir>` worked.

Answer (score 1):

To install **custom plugin** through **CLI** use below command

```
cordova plugin add (Add your plugin path here)
```

Eg.

```
cordova plugin add C:\Users\project\custom_camera_plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

try using GIT Url. example :    $ cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console.git

Answer (score 0):

You should use [plugman](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/plugman.html) to manage custom plugins.

To install:

```
$ plugman install --platform <ios|android|blackberry10|wp8> --project <directory> --plugin <name|url|path> [--plugins_dir <directory>] [--www <directory>] [--variable <name>=<value> [--variable <name>=<value> ...]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find good documentation in this link

https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/createplugintutorial/

however after making your own plugin you can edit your java and javascript file and publish it to npm again by updating version in npm
using 
npm version patch 
and npm publish .

and hence by this you can use it

however if you want to make it without publishing it on npm  then i also dont know that
if you find then please tell?
(Respond back in case of any questions)